# web-console is not working in all views on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To have web-console available on all pages (not just the error pages), I added the following line:

```
<%= console %>
```

in *app/views/layouts/application.html.erb*

The problem is that the web-console shows up in all pages, **except** for pages from a certain controller.

When checking the view-page-source, it is also not there (so it is not hidden or something like that).

I'm running in development mode using Ruby 2.3.1 on Rails 5.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the following line in the controller that did not work.

```
include ActionController::Live
```

Commenting this line solved the problem. It seems that web-console does not work with controllers that have ActionController::Live included. Will move the 'actions' that uses ActionController::Live to a separate controller.

Comment: also the chrome extension RailsPanel, that uses the 'meta_request' gem, does not work with a controller that has ActionController::Live included.

Answer (score 0):

rails web-console may not appear on error pages. Updating from old version to new one helps:

```
gem 'web-console', '>= 3.6.2'
```